# In/from which preposition to use?

Tags: prepositions

What college are you **(in/from)**?

When trying to find out what college someone goes to, do we ask them "What college are you?", or "What college are you in?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Which college do you go to?
- What college do you go to?
- Which college do you attend?
- What college do you attend?
- Where do you go (to college)?

These are the most common ways (or at least, the first that came to mind) of asking someone which college they attend.. they are in no specific order.